# Ideas for my MSc project and Google Summer of Code 2011

Tags: development

I'm currently putting together ideas for my master's project which I'll be working on over the summer, and I would like to be able to use this time to help Ubuntu in some way. I have the freedom to come up with pretty much any project in the field of software development/engineering provided it

- Is a substantial piece of software (for reference, I will be working on it for five full months)
- Solves a problem for more people than just myself

I was hoping to use this project as an opportunity to get some experience with the underbelly of Linux, so that I can mention on my CV that I have 'experience in developing for *NIX in C++', which I'm noticing more and more companies are looking for these days, probably because stuff's moving to cloud servers and that's where Linux rules the roost.

My problem is that, since I don't have the experience to begin with, I'm not sure what to do for such a project, and I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. I've noticed from [Daniel Holbach's blog](http://daniel.holba.ch/blog/?p=635) that Ubuntu participated in the Google Summer of Code 2010, and that project ideas for that can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GoogleSoC2010/Ideas). However, I have not been able to find anything related to Ubuntu and GSoC 2011, but I have noticed from the [GSoC timeline](http://www.google-melange.com/document/show/gsoc_program/google/gsoc2011/timeline) that the list of mentoring organisations will not be published until March 18th.

I have two questions here. Has Ubuntu applied to be a part of Summer of Code 2011, and what is the status of the 2010 project list linked to earlier. Were they all implemented or are there still some that can be picked up now, should I not participate in GSoC? I'd like to do something for Ubuntu, but I'd rather not spend my time reinventing the wheel.

**Update**: Jono Bacon has [confirmed on his weekly Q&A](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/at-home-with-jono-bacon) that Ubuntu has filed it's application for GSoC 2011. I'll leave this question open until the wiki page for the project ideas is available. That said, ideas are still welcome ;)

Comment: Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The first part of your question has been answered. The part about suggestions is too localised. It depends on what the OP is interested in doing and what he's willing to do, there isn't a correct answer for everyone. Also, this is about GSoc 2011, which is no longer relevant. Let's close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have published the GSoC 2011 list of mentoring organisations, and Ubuntu isn't there. turns out they didn't get accepted this year.

Comment: you could still pick a project by one of the accepted *nix related groups like the linux foundation or GNU?

Comment: Yeah, I'm checking them out.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I Would check out [brainstorm.ubuntu.com](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) for some Ideas of a program sized hole in Ubuntu that would fit your requirements.

My own suggestion for something cool (not a programmer) would be to create a torrent based package management system making it almost impossible to have problems getting updates.

Any way I'm sure other people have better ideas than me but I think is a good question I thought I would get the ball rolling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check out brainstorm. And the torrent-based package manager sounds pretty cool to.

Comment: Just one of those too much coffee moments but it would be nice to see torrent used for something better than downloading films. One of my other reasons is because linux makes it possible for more people to access computing and anything that helps that can't be bad!!

Comment: I really like the idea, really smart!! Ohh, Chris, if are going to apply, good luck, and remember to write the best application!!